# Duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' IIS & Web.config

Tags: .net, wcf

IIS contains an entry for security authentication, my release management seems to require the same entry in the web.config, with just the IIS instance of the setting it works but release management wont, and with both I receive the following error;

**ERROR**

> > "There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined", this error is because you are running a .NET Framework 3.5-based application in .NET Framework 4. If you are running WebMatrix, to resolve this problem, go to the Settings node to set the .NET Framework version to ".NET 2". You can also remove the extra sections from the web.config file.

**WEB.CONFIG**

```
<security>
 <authentication>
  <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
  <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
 </authentication>
</security>
```

**What are my options in regards to managing these settings?**

Comment: -1 Your question is....?

Comment: @Tim, What are my options in regards to managing these settings?